# Selecting two Fields from two different tables as one (using Join) (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, select, join

I've got the following SQL, selecting articles in two different ways. All articles are stored in the Articles table. Some are marked as Article Of The Month (Articles_Fitness), while others are marked as purely fitness articles (ArticlesInCategories).

**My problem is that I need to select both Articles_Fitness.StartDate and Articles.PublicationDate as the Formatted_Date.** Is this possible, or will I need to label one as Formatted_Date1 and Formatted_Date2, and then check when I output it?

```
SELECT 
       Articles.ArticleID, 
       Articles.Title, 
       Articles.Author, 
       Articles.Abstract, 
       date_format(Articles_Fitness.StartDate, '%M %d, %Y') AS Formatted_Date,
       date_format(Articles.PublicationDate, '%M %d, %Y') AS Formatted_Date
     FROM 
       Articles 
       LEFT JOIN Articles_Fitness
            ON Articles_Fitness.ArticleID = Articles.ArticleID
            AND Articles_Fitness.StartDate <= CURDATE()
       LEFT JOIN ArticlesInCategories 
            ON ArticlesInCategories.ArticleID = Articles.ArticleID
            AND ArticlesInCategories.CategoryID = '1'
     WHERE 
       Articles.Body IS NOT NULL AND
       Articles.Body != '' AND
       Articles.Public ='1'
```

Comment: Beside the output formatting problem, I see a (potential) major issue with how you are selecting articles. Do you want the output to include articles with ArticleInCategories.CategoryID = '1' and to also include articles in Articles_Fitness (that meet the start date criterion), or do you want an article to appear in the output only if BOTH things are true?

Comment: I want it to include articles if ONE is true.

Comment: For what it's worth you can collapse the Articles.Body WHERE constraints into one:  `Articles.Body != ''`.  That will be false if the field is null.

Comment: Is the query selecting the rows that you want? Scanning the syntax, it looks like it would return all rows in the Article table that meet the WHERE criteria, regardless of whether they meet the criteria involving the other two tables (since LEFT JOIN returns all rows in the left hand table, with NULL in the columns from the right hand table if there isn't a matching row).

Comment: I believe it is UltraOne, but I'm not 100% positive; I'm updating an old query to include the articles in ArticlesInCategories; it used to only grab articles from Articles_Fitness. I'll do a more thorough search to see if its grabbing exactly what I want. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying you want `Articles_Fitness.StartDate` if present, otherwise `Articles.PublicationDate`?  You can return that in one column:

```
...
DATE_FORMAT(COALESCE(Articles_Fitness.StartDate, Articles.PublicationDate),
            '%M %d, %Y') AS Formatted_Date
...
```

Comment: I have not seen COALESCE before. Thank you very much!